Java concurrency problem with enums and references
I'm having a concurrency problem when I update an object through an Enum's referenced field.
Code here on jdoodle and Github.
After setting the object's field, with the method Car#start through UpdatePolicy, I can see that it is updated to a wrong value. Using Car#start directly is however fine.
Also if I remove the enum (named State), problem goes away. I think somehow Enum's field level variables are not thread-safe.
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture;

public class Scratch {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (int x = 0; x < 100; x++) {
      List<CompletableFuture<Void>> futures = new ArrayList<>();
      for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        int finalI = i;
        futures.add(CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> startCar(String.valueOf(finalI))));
      }
      CompletableFuture.allOf(futures.toArray(new CompletableFuture[0])).join();
    }
  }


  private static void startCar(String index) {
    var car = new Car();
    car.getUpdatePolicy().start(index);
    if (!index.equals(car.getJourneyId())) {
      throw new RuntimeException("Expected journeyId to be " + index + " but was " + car.getJourneyId());
    }
  }

  static class Car {

    private State state = State.OFF;
    private String journeyId;

    public UpdatePolicy getUpdatePolicy() {
      return state.getJobUpdatePolicy(this);
    }

    public void start(String journeyId) {
      this.journeyId = journeyId;
    }

    public String getJourneyId() {
      return journeyId;
    }
  }

  enum State {
    OFF(new UpdatePolicy() {
      @Override
      public void start(String journeyId) {
        car.start(journeyId);
      }
    });

    private final UpdatePolicy updatePolicy;

    State(UpdatePolicy updatePolicy) {
      this.updatePolicy = updatePolicy;
    }

    public UpdatePolicy getJobUpdatePolicy(Car car) {
      return updatePolicy.withContext(car);
    }
  }

  abstract static class UpdatePolicy {

    Car car;

    public abstract void start(String journeyId);

    public UpdatePolicy withContext(Car car) {
      this.car = car;
      return this;
    }
  }
}


There is only one instance of OFF, and therefore one instance of its UpdatePolicy. With two threads running, one call to withContext(car) will be wiping the details of the other. You need to re-think the structure, either avoid having car field in UpdatePolicy or create new one per update.

Your UpdatePolicy is not thread safe. Why do you think it should be thread safe?

“I think somehow Enum's field level variables are not thread-safe” — No, they are not thread-safe. An enum is basically a class, albeit slightly special. So, like any other class, the member fields are not inherently thread-safe. You must take precautions to make them thread-safe. What made you think enum member fields would be thread-safe?

@DuncG when you say that there is only one instance of OFF, I'm a bit lost. The enum belongs to the Car, which is constructed separately for each Thread. From all these answers I feel that Enums are very static, just like how a static class would be.

Enums have only 1 instance, so you assign singleton (State.OFF) different cars in different threads, causing some cars to update journeyId multiple times, and other are losing updates.
You can avoid it, by creating new updatePolicy for each car.
enum State {
  OFF();

  public UpdatePolicy getJobUpdatePolicy(Car car) {
    return new UpdatePolicy() {
      @Override
      public void start(String journeyId) {
        car.start(journeyId);
      }
    }.withContext(car);
  }
}


Thanks for the explanation! Can you explain in detail, what do you mean by Enums have only 1 instance? How does this behaviour differ from a class? Even though I constructed everything fresh for each thread, how do they still collide each other? Enums are behaving like static classes then, or?

enum State{OFF, ON} has 2 instances. Off is separate instance, and ON is separate instance. So each enum value is a singleton, meaning there is just 1 instance of it. Basically enum class difference in this case is that you can create instances of classes (new Car()), but you cannot create new instance of state (new State.OFF()), as there can only be one instance of State.OFF
